# Blue floaters in canned hot peppers

Tags: canning, chili-peppers, bell-peppers

I've canned hot peppers for years. This year I've developed little blue floaters in the jars. I've never seen this. Does anyone know what this might be???

Comment: really?  blue? bright blue, turquoisey-blue? purpley-blue? freaky! -- do you have a picture? what shapes are they?

Comment: Little light blue flakes

Comment: Very new users cannot add pictures yet. Upload the picture somewhere else, for example on imgur.com, and post the link in a comment. We will edit it into the post for you. Sorry for the roundabout thing, it is a protection against spammers and other unsavory types who register only to start posting pictures nobody wants to see.

Comment: What is your canning process/recipe, in detail? Many things that "Grandma always did this way" in canning turn out to be somewhat dubious (others turn out to be just fine, such as the vindication of (properly) steaming as equivalent to boiling water immersion, though despite now being research proven for over a year, the word gets out slowly.) But for peppers, unless you are pickling them to make them acidic, a pressure canner is required for safe canning. My first thought with blue is mold of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

This is a few months late, but just in case you haven't resolved this some other way, I'd say that:

First, don't eat them. I think it would be best to contact your local University Extension Service (if you are in the states) which will often have access to USDA proper canning methods. It's likely that they would know what this is or could recommend how to find out. They are exactly where I go when I find a weird spider in the garden and that type of thing. Good luck!